# How do ASP.NET Identity framework (forms) with bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-identity

I'm doing an **ASP.NET Web Application with Identity** with this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

But I would like to the **form with bootstrap** like that:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

But the **form with .aspx** is so:

```
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="StatusMessage" />
</p>                
<div style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />                
    </div>
</div>
```

How it should be?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use the built in asp.net login control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is to add the css class's of `bootstrap` to the asp.net controls, and what other attributes you may like as:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username" />                
</div>
```